# How to change istio global parameter in sidecar inject-config.yaml

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I am trying to change istio global config parameter `initialDelaySeconds` value in  inject-config.yaml

```
initialDelaySeconds: [[ annotation .ObjectMeta `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/initialDelaySeconds`  1  ]]
```

when i try below code sample for my `initialDelaySeconds` i am getting error..

```
$ kubectl get cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml | sed -e "s initialDelaySeconds: 1/ initialDelaySeconds: 10/" | kubectl apply -f -
```

Getting below error

```
 sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'
 error: no objects passed to apply
 error: write /dev/stdout: The pipe has been ended.
```

what is correct syntax to change my global parameter in sidecar inject-config.xml

Also below code snippet works for me for `rewriteAppHTTPProbe`

```
$ kubectl get cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml | sed -e "s/ rewriteAppHTTPProbe: false/ rewriteAppHTTPProbe: true/" | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: why dont you just do `kubectl edit cm istio-sidecar-injector`?

Comment: no it doenst work

Comment: how come it doesnt work? it sure does. whats the error?

Comment: Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "istio-sidecar-injector" not found getting this error

Comment: well, you joking or something, you need to add namespace to the command. `kubectl edit cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system`. i just didnt want to type it because its obvious

Comment: pls add to this to the answer.. this works..

Comment: doesn't work for me. Same as in my answer, values are getting reverted to the default values within couple of seconds

Comment: it is working mate.. it is not changing to my default value..

Comment: @pappu_kutty are you using istio on GKE ?

Comment: @A_Suh i am using istio on AKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just use `kubectl edit` to edit the configmap:

```
kubectl edit cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system
```

Comment: Does it really work? For me the value of initialDelaySeconds parameter getting reverted to the default value?

Comment: if its getting reverted - means something is setting it to that value. kubernetes resources do not revert themselves to previous version

Comment: fair enough, how to find what? what I have also tried is scaled down deployment to 0, removed cm and re-created it from yaml, but  no luck

Comment: raise a question

Comment: Kubernetes has an "addon" mechanism. When Istio is installed as an addon – all it's resources are labelled as `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile`. Every edit made to them will be automatically reverted. This is used by the kubernetes host (like GKE) to have their own stuff running in a stable mode (like dashboard, loadbalancer, istio, admission controllers, CNI plugins, auth, etc).

So this is a general addon-mode problem, and I'm not sure if Istio allow second-level config.

Answer (score 1):

share the below yaml file if possible
istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml

try this

```
kubectl get cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml | sed -e "s/rewriteAppHTTPProbe: false/grewriteAppHTTPProbe: true/g" | kubectl apply -f -


master $ cat testfile
initialDelaySeconds: [[ annotation .ObjectMeta `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/initialDelaySeconds`  1]]

sed -i '/initialDelaySeconds:/c\initialDelaySeconds: 10' testfile

master $ cat testfile
initialDelaySeconds: 10
```

Comment: rewriteAppHTTPProbe this works for me.. but i want to change global config in sidecar and i want to change the value initialDelaySeconds , not rewriteAppHTTPProbe

Answer (score 1):

Regular `kubectl edit cm` will work only for open source Istio.

Otherwise, if you are using Istio as GKE cluster add-on it'll be a bit tricky, because all edits are getting reconciled by mixer running on the master node. What you can do is to dump your configmap --> `injection-cm`, make edits you want and then use it for manual injections, i.e.

```
istioctl kube-inject -f deployment.yaml --injectConfigMapName injection-cm
```

More info [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/#istioctl-kube-inject)

Comment: this command works . but not updating the value.. i am still seeing the old value in  inject-config.yaml   initialDelaySeconds:    ' [[ annotation .ObjectMeta readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/initialDelaySeconds`  1  ]]'

Comment: @pappu_kutty actually the values are getting changed and  in couple of seconds getting reverted

Comment: @pappu_kutty I've updated my answer for the future reference. I know it's not your case, but maybe someone like me will encounter the same problem with Istio for GKE